# Why is unrelated variable affecting another variable? moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have this code. `start` is 30m before `end`.
When I subtract another 5m, it affects `end` too:

```
let start = moment().subtract(30,"m");
let end = moment();

console.log(start);  // 11:00
console.log(end); // 11:30

start = end.subtract(35,"m");

console.log(start); // 10:55
console.log(end); // 10:55
```

I understand why this is happening - because the [subtract()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/) method mutates the variable it is called on. So I used another variable `new_time` to try and stop `end` from being affected:

```
let start = moment().subtract(30,"m");
let end = moment();

console.log(start); // 11:00
console.log(end); // 11:30

let new_time = end;
start = new_time.subtract(35,"m");

console.log(start); // 10:55
console.log(end); // 10:55
```

But `end` is still being affected! Why?! How can I get my code to work...

Example codepen here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BvXGEW

Edit: I've just read about [moment cloning](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/), which I can use to solve my issue, but I still don't understand how assigning a totally different variable can affect the original variable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

`let new_time = end;`

copies the reference of `end` object to `new_time`. Thus, both variables refer to the same object. There is only one object and two variables referring to it.

The solution:

`let new_time = moment(end);`

which creates another moment object and assigns it to `new_time` variable. Now you have 2 different objects.

Answer (score 1):

Methods like `subtract` don't act on variables but on objects. Variables are just there to reference / access those objects which live in memory.

Writing `new_time = end` just means that the object accessible by `end` is now available by `new_time`, too.
Therefore any changes to the object referenced by `end` are equally visible when looking at `new_time`.

If you want them to be independent you should indeed clone `end` before applying any changes to it.

Comment: Thanks. Huh...now questioning everything I thought I understood about javascript...!